# Restful routes and Django

Tags: django, rest

I'm in a process of migrating Rails project into Django.  Rails project was built using restful routes and it never touches the database.  Instead, it simply redirects to different methods which all call an external service with the specified action method.  Now, I have found a number of frameworks for django that provide restful capability plus a bunch of bells and whistles, but it's an overkill for my current case.

As an alternative, I can ignore action method in urls.py by simply providing a regex to validate urls and then parse the request method in views.py, redirecting to the appropriate method.  Is this a way to go or are there any other approaches that I can look at?

Answer (score 3):

[Class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/releases/1.3/#class-based-views) look like the idiomatic way to organize restful view functions by request method.

Django snippets has several simple [example](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1071/) [implementations](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/437/).

Comment: I got answer for my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522310/want-to-learn-django-with-rest-without-rest-framworks