# Want to learn django with REST without rest frameworks

Tags: python, django, rest

I am a php programmer, I have built some REST based solutions in php. Now I am learning python/django. I want to make a REST based solution in Django ( only for knowledge purpose ). I do not want to use any of REST frameworks/toolkits as This project is more a exploring django/python say how they work with raw REST concept.

I searched on net, But examples/tutorial filled on already built solutions. I also checkout for request method based filtering. I am thinking of two approaches.

Either urls.py have way to check request method and transfer to respective method in views.py.
Or I can add a pre load hook/class which determine request method on application initialize, And called respective method so overriding urls.py behavior (my preferred method).

If anybody can suggest a django way to do this?

Update : I found some interesting comments on SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898410/1230744 AND https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732520/1230744. Need to check if they can have the solution, I am searching.

Comment: This is a question and answer site.  This should be a question, but appears to be a statement.  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I get the answer of my questions finally from following link. It is possible through using Class based Views + serialization.

[Restful routes and Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856355/restful-routes-and-django)

Snippet links in side above link gave pretty much example to gave quite picture of how one can create a REST Api using only Django Core. Also I used serialize https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/ for Json encoding

( Now if anybody prefer, he can flag duplicate the question. ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can start from learning the code of this projects:

- http://tastypieapi.org/ Tastypie
- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/ Django REST framework

They are snadrd de facto for REST API for Django and their code could be a good starting point.

Also, please review this questions:

- [Creating a REST API for a Django application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577177/creating-a-rest-api-for-a-django-application)
- [Adding REST to Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308605/adding-rest-to-django)
- [Django and Restful APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656979/django-and-restful-apis)

Comment: REST is not very hard thing in concept, So making a small app on pure REST concepts, should not need to learn a full fledged application source code. I agree they must have done a good code architecture. But my requirement is so small. Meanwhile I have found something interesting as I linked in my updated answer. If they works then that should be what I am searching. Just small and clear.